# Simplify3D and Davinci mini

Tags: software, simplify3d

**Simplify3D** is listing the **XYZprinting Davinci mini** as a compatible printer for their software. I would never buy such expensive software in combination with this printer if I didn't already think of buying a better printer.

Can anybody confirm compatibility with 'out of the box' configuration and up to date firmware?

Comment: Be aware that Simplify3D offers what they call "Risk-Free Guarantee": the possibility to try the software for 2 weeks and get refunded 100% if you aren't fully satisfied.

Comment: @tmartin Why you need this information if you never would buy the software? but... works great!

Comment: @FernandoBaltazar read the whole sentence, not only the 1st half.

Comment: @tmartin you have my answer in my comment, not in the question.

Answer (score 2):

XYZPrinting printers use a .3w file format vs GCode on all opensource printer designs.  I have used Simplify3D since the first month I obtained my Da Vinci Pro 3 in 1 which also has WiFi enabled.

Simplify3D does not connect very well to my Da Vinci WiFi so a 25ft ActiveUSB extension makes the connection for uploading and monitoring the progress of the print.

All the XYZPrinting Da Vinci series are available on the printer configuration wizard if not then sending a request to Simplify3D will obtain a response with the printer configuration file.